# fastest way to remove property from json in mysql text field

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table with >100MM rows. They have a result text column that contains a json string like this:

```
{"location":"us","name":"Jon Doe","html":"<html>...</html>"}
```

I would like to remove html or to set it null:

```
{"location":"us","name":"Jon Doe","html":null}
```

The straightforward way would be to load the rows in code, then json decode them, set html null and save them again. however this will take forever for all rows.

Is there a more performant way to do it with a query?

Comment: what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @HaleemurAli 5.6.40

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the results derived by `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function searching for `<html` pattern in the left to right direction, and for `'/html>'` pattern reversely :

```
UPDATE tab
   SET json_col = CONCAT(
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(json_col,'<html',1),
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(json_col,'/html>',-1))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f5b9d2fcc5b541b57f2d66d50d76c7b6)</kbd>